# how to scroll by index in datatable flutter

Tags: flutter

I have 2000+ Rows in datatable and I want to scroll to `DataRow.byIndex` by search index

```
DataTable(
    columns: const <DataColumn>[
    DataColumn(
        label: Text(
          'Number',
        ),
      ),
      DataColumn(
        label: Text(
          'Amount',
        ),
      ),
      DataColumn(
        label: Text(
          'Delete',
        ),
      ),
    ],
    rows: [
      for (int i = 0; i < _jodies.length; i++)
        DataRow.byIndex(index: i, cells: <DataCell>[
          DataCell(Text(_jodies[i]['number']
                      .toString()
                      .length ==
                  1
              ? '0${_jodies[i]['number'].toString()}'
              : _jodies[i]['number'].toString())),
          DataCell(Text(
              _jodies[i]['amount'].toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: selectedJodi == i
                      ? Colors.red
                      : Colors.black))),
          DataCell(
            IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(
                Icons.delete_forever,
                color: Colors.red,
                size: 24.0,
              ),
              highlightColor: Colors.red,
              onPressed: () {
                _showDeleteConfirmation(i, 'jodi');
              },
            ),
          ),
        ]),
    ],
  ),
```

how can I scroll to particular row